# Divergence for Series with $|a_n| \ge b_n \ge 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

first of all i hope you get my point since English is not my native.

I know the series $$ y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} $$ is divergent.

Now I want to check if the series $$x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2(k+1)} $$ is divergent too.

I "have" to use the criteria with $$ |a_k| \ge d_k \ge 0 $$ in Germany it is called Minorante.

So when $\sum d_k$ is divergent obviously $\sum a_k$ is divergent too. 
In my case with an indexshift we can put $$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2(k+1)} $$ into $$ 1/2 * \sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k $$

We see when we shift the Index in the other formula $$ y = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/k $$ to $$ y = \sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k $$ we have nearly the same expression only that we have a *1/2 on $x_k$.

My question is, the definition is $$ |a_k| \ge d_k \ge 0. $$ For our case $$ x \ge y \ge 0 $$ 
Why is our $x_k = a_k $ and our $y_k = d_k $?

Because $ y = \sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k $ is $\gt$ than $ x = 1/2*\sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k $

Or do we ignore the 1/2*? Then it would be at least equal and the definition would be okay.

My solution from the university says: We know $y = \sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k$ is divergent so we can conclude with the defintion $|a_k| \ge d_k \ge 0$ that $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 1/(2(k+1))$ is divergent too.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange. There are several issues with your question. (1) If $|a_k| \ge d_k > 0$ and the series $\sum_k d_k$ diverges, it does **not** follow that the series $\sum_k a_k$ diverges. This is only true if all (or almost all) $a_k$ are positive or negative. (2) You can't write something like $y_k = \sum_k a_k$, since the index $k$ is a dummy variable and the result of the series does not depend on $k$. To understand the argument in your notes/solution key, write down what it would mean for the first 4 or 6 terms.

Comment: @HansEngler to (1) 
Since we only use natural Numbers I think we ignore this since it will always be positive right?
(2) Yeah sorry I know that. I don't know why I wrote y_k etc. I corrected it.

Well, for y we would have 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 ...
For x we would have 1/4+ 1/6 + 1/8...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

- $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2(k+1)}=\frac{1}{2k+2}\ge\frac{1}{4k}, \forall k\in \mathbb{N}.$
- The series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4k}=\frac 14 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ is divergent.

Comment: Thanks! 
I know its divergent and your solutions makes much more sense to me. But I don't get it why the university solution concludes the divergence from 1/k. Since $\sum_{i=2}^\infty 1/k $ > $1/2*\sum_{i=2}^\infty 1/k $

Comment: Why do you think that? Just take $d_k=\frac{1}{4k}.$

Comment: I don't think that. It is the pattern solution from my university which says this. I guess there is a mistake.